# View close votes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[Privileges page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/privileges) states that `view close votes` requieres 250 reputations, however the [review page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/) states :

```
You need at least 500 reputation to review Close Votes.
```

Which one is the right one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both are correct.  While you only need 250 reputation to **view** close votes (i.e. see how many close votes have been cast on a question), you still need 500 reputation to actually [**cast** close votes](https://islam.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions).

One of the requirements of going through the Close Votes review queue is figuring out whether you need to add your own close vote into the mix; as such, the larger 500 reputation requirement to cast a vote is the minimum for review.